# Как динамически менять информацию в шаблоне через пхп?

Tags: php, html

У меня есть попап типа -

```
<div class="open-popup modal fade" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
    <div class="popup-container">
        <div class="popup">
            <div class="popup-content">
                <div class="popup-block">
                    <div id="popupIscroll">
                        <?php echo Main_PopupTemplate::displayText(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="close" data-dismiss="modal"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

В зависимости от страницы классы и текст попапа меняются. Смену текста я уже реализовал, метод получает по  маркеру на страннице нужный текст. Текста хранятся в шаблонах. С классамы сложнее, как-то не хочется утыкать весь шаблон вызывами  методов. При чем проще тогда наплодить шаблонов для каждой страницы. Но хочу использовать один шаблон. Шаблонизатор не подходит мне. Как это возможно реализовать, если возможно?

Comment: не понял в чем проблема
можешь повторить? что мешает в функции displayText() свой аргумент вставить displayText(sometext);